# Anaconda is not updating Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I updated anaconda once through a window notification and also by using the terminal and typing:

```
conda update conda
```

However, when I start Spyder I get the message that there are newer versions available. I tried to update Spyder with the terminal by using:

```
conda update spyder
```

However, Spyder still does not get updated. Here you see the screenshot of the terminal:[image: Screenshot_Anaconda_Terminal]

For me this is confusing. Does someone of you have an idea, why conda is not updating spyer? I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the output, I'd say you need python 3.7 to upgrade spyder. What version of python do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This was just a typo in the post. In the terminal I used the correct spelling.

Comment: Edited. Check it out

Comment: Thanks Merciful for your answer. I do not really know which Python version I have (I am a beginner). I have Anaconda 1.9.12

Comment: Find out then or install python 3.7

Comment: I have python 3.6.1

Comment: You have the latest version of spyder for python 3.6.1. To update spyder you need python 3.7.

Comment: Thanks Merciful for your comment. I tried to update Python by using the command in the terminal: "conda install python=3.7pythonversion3.7". Unfortunately it does not work. I get an error message telling somehting about packages that could not be found.

Comment: I know managed to update Python and consequently Spyder was also updated. Thanks for your help (I accepted your answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think u have made spelling mistake , its `conda update spyder`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This was just a typo in the post. In the terminal I used the correct spelling.

Comment: I am not sure but as you have tried it many times can you once again try to update using the same command but run it in the anaconda prompt as administrator

Comment: Thanks Arpit for your comment. Unfotunately it did not help. The problem still persists.

Comment: One last hope conda install spyder=version --force-reinstall . Try this also in administrator anaconda prompt